# What happened to Models in CinchV2?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, cinch

In CinchV1 there was a section of Sacha's CodeProject post which described how to develop Models with Cinch. Now, looking at the documentation for CinchV2, all I can find out about models is this:

> 4 Developing Models Using Cinch
>
> ```
>       NOTE : This is no longer possible in Cinch V2
> ```

Clearly, I am missing something, right? I mean, it's not the 'VVM' Pattern, is it?

**What exactly does it mean when it says "This is no longer possible in Cinch V2"?**

**If Models are no longer used, what should I do in place of using them?**

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cinch, but your models should not depend on any framework except the .Net Framework. Models should be POCO classes, and not inherit from anything, except maybe implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but that's it

Comment: HighCore, thanks for your feedback. I am aware that I can make a Model class just using INPC, but my real question is more about why the documentation doesn't speak of it at all. Also, there's a sample project for V2, and it doesn't use any models, only ViewModels.

Comment: I guess that's a matter of "the M part of MVVM is up to you"... you're free to implement it in any way you want

Answer (score 2):

So the answer was buried in a part of the CodeProject post I didn't see. Here is what it says:

> As I just stated, Cinch does actually allow you to either expose a CurrentXXXModel off your
>   ViewModel which supports DataWrappers/Validation Rules (IDataErrorInfo) / ViewMode
>   changes / IEditableObject operations, by use of the two Cinch Model classes mentioned
>   above.
>
> But as I also stated above, I **no longer** recommend that approach, and think that the Model
>   should be left alone, and that you should do all your DataWrappers/Validation Ruless
>   (IDataErrorInfo) / ViewMode changes /IEditableObject operations in your ViewModel.

**1.) It is no longer preferred to write a Model that is inherited from a Cinch base class. Models are still used in CinchV2, but binding a View to a Model is no longer preferred.**

**2.) Write Models as you normally would, but only use DataWrappers and such in the ViewModel.**

Comment: Isn't this precisely what I was talking about? =)